# YouTube search operators in API call? booelan operator AND, OR and NOT

Tags: youtube-data-api, boolean-logic

i am having difficulty to discover how the operator AND function for a research with Youtube API.

At the Youtube.Search i found the method setQ that explaing the logic for the operator NOT and OR but not for the operator AND.
The main idea is to make a search that contains exactly both 2 parameters otherelse i can use the OR logic.

Example: i want that 2 "fish" and "sea" should be both part of the metadata of the research.

I have made an analysis on front-end call and it has this form:
fish+sea but if i try to implement it in java it looks that it doesn't function correctly cause i have other results.
PS: I have ordered all my results by relevance ( by setting the order with "relevance" value as the logic that youtube itself use)
For this reason i was wating to have the same result on youtube website and in my local app.

Answer (score 1):

I tested some request using the Google Data API Explorer and I found that the word "**AND**" *(uppercase)* it will bring you *slightly different* results:

For example, the following request is for search videos using the query "The ring" *(without double quotes)* - it will bring the top 10 search results from the US region:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=10&q=The+ring&regionCode=US&type=video&fields=items(id(channelId%2Ckind%2CvideoId)%2Csnippet(channelTitle%2Ctitle))%2CnextPageToken%2CpageInfo%2CprevPageToken%2CregionCode%2CtokenPagination&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

These are the results:

```
{
 "nextPageToken": "CAoQAA",
 "regionCode": "US",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1000000,
  "resultsPerPage": 10
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "PFsl1cGHzp4"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "title": "The Ring (1/8) Movie CLIP - You Will Die in Seven Days (2002) HD",
    "channelTitle": "Movieclips"
   }
  },
  {
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "lbO9LhD9PsI"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "title": "The Ring- final scene!",
    "channelTitle": "prochys09"
   }
  },
  {
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "5bXpMRkwm_8"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "title": "SML Movie: The Ring",
    "channelTitle": "SuperMarioLogan"
   }
  },
  {
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "V3iJqH9-tQ8"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "title": "Everything Wrong With The Ring In 14 Minutes Or Less",
    "channelTitle": "CinemaSins"
   }
  },
  {
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "lm9AoNNWiPc"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "title": "The Ring Evolution in Movies &amp; TV. (Sadako &amp; Samara)",
    "channelTitle": "Darwin's Media"
   }
  },
  {
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "hpb2-ZOzc_o"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "title": "Samara Comes to You - The Ring (8/8) Movie CLIP (2002) HD",
    "channelTitle": "Movieclips"
   }
  },
  {
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "Baw98nsMvxU"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "title": "scary movie 3 brenda vs the ring lol",
    "channelTitle": "maltbydude"
   }
  },
  {
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "6YP1xg8G1o4"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "title": "RINGS behind the scenes",
    "channelTitle": "teu davidz"
   }
  },
  {
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "rroMPRc4flw"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "title": "The Ring Two (8/8) Movie CLIP - I&#39;m Not Your Mommy (2005) HD",
    "channelTitle": "Movieclips"
   }
  },
  {
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "WcuRPzB4RNc"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "title": "Rings (2017) - TV Store Prank",
    "channelTitle": "Paramount Pictures"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Here is the [demo](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list?part=snippet&maxResults=10&q=The%20ring&regionCode=US&type=video&fields=items(id(channelId%252CvideoId)%252Csnippet(channelId%252CchannelTitle%252Cdescription%252Ctitle))%252CnextPageToken%252CpageInfo%252CprevPageToken%252CregionCode&_h=1&) of the previous request.

Making a test with these modifications:

- Double quote the searchs terms - *(i.e. `"the"`, `"ring"`)*.
- Adding the "**AND**" operator *(without double quotes)*.

I can now test the modified version of the previous request:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=10&q=%22The%22+AND+%22ring%22&regionCode=US&type=video&fields=items(id(channelId%2Ckind%2CvideoId)%2Csnippet(channelTitle%2Ctitle))%2CnextPageToken%2CpageInfo%2CprevPageToken%2CregionCode%2CtokenPagination&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

And its results:

```
{
 "nextPageToken": "CAoQAA",
 "regionCode": "US",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1000000,
  "resultsPerPage": 10
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "PFsl1cGHzp4"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "title": "The Ring (1/8) Movie CLIP - You Will Die in Seven Days (2002) HD",
    "channelTitle": "Movieclips"
   }
  },
  {
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "5bXpMRkwm_8"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "title": "SML Movie: The Ring",
    "channelTitle": "SuperMarioLogan"
   }
  },
  {
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "lbO9LhD9PsI"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "title": "The Ring- final scene!",
    "channelTitle": "prochys09"
   }
  },
  {
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "V3iJqH9-tQ8"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "title": "Everything Wrong With The Ring In 14 Minutes Or Less",
    "channelTitle": "CinemaSins"
   }
  },
  {
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "hpb2-ZOzc_o"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "title": "Samara Comes to You - The Ring (8/8) Movie CLIP (2002) HD",
    "channelTitle": "Movieclips"
   }
  },
  {
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "rroMPRc4flw"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "title": "The Ring Two (8/8) Movie CLIP - I&#39;m Not Your Mommy (2005) HD",
    "channelTitle": "Movieclips"
   }
  },
  {
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "lm9AoNNWiPc"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "title": "The Ring Evolution in Movies &amp; TV. (Sadako &amp; Samara)",
    "channelTitle": "Darwin's Media"
   }
  },
  {
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "kcRWyLMVrFM"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "title": "Cardi B - Ring (feat. Kehlani) [Official Video]",
    "channelTitle": "Cardi B"
   }
  },
  {
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "uukQ_6szDm8"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "title": "Rings | Trailer #1 | Paramount Pictures International",
    "channelTitle": "Paramount Pictures International"
   }
  },
  {
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "3SZu3_HGoWk"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "title": "Samara Sings A Song (The Ring Scary Halloween Parody)",
    "channelTitle": "Aaron Fraser-Nash"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Here is the [demo](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list?part=snippet&maxResults=10&q=%2522The%2522%20AND%20%2522ring%2522&regionCode=US&type=video&fields=items(id(channelId%252Ckind%252CvideoId)%252Csnippet(channelTitle%252Ctitle))%252CnextPageToken%252CpageInfo%252CprevPageToken%252CregionCode%252CtokenPagination&_h=4&) of the previous request.

If you compare the two results, you'll see that *(using the **AND** operator)* does not contain these search results:

> N.B: I highlighted the search terms:

- scary movie 3 brenda vs **the ring** lol
- **RING**S behind **the** scenes
- **Ring**s (2017) - TV Store Prank

Instead, the new results are:

- Cardi B - **Ring** (feat. Kehlani) [Official Video]
- Samara Sings A Song (**The Ring** Scary Halloween Parody)
- **Ring**s | Trailer #1 | Paramount Pictures International

I think there is no much variation in the results after all.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply.
I have read tons of different artciles and in one of them that i dont remember the link was saying tht the logic operator AND is not used anymore on google.
Cause google has buy youtube i think that they has disable this operator to.
The reason was to mke more human readable the query ( so even for us that we program i think that AND ( before was the symbol + ) doesn't function.
Even double quotes (" first second third " ) doesn't make a correct search for the operator AND. Arrange the search with double quotes and some filters.