# Boolean OR in Youtube API v 3 (Python code)

Tags: python, youtube-api, boolean

I am having trouble with a Python code. The code works perfectly with a single query:

```
   response = youtube.search().list(
            part="id, snippet",
            maxResults=50,
            q="searchterm",
            type="video"
         ).execute()
```

I have tried q= "firstterm" and q= "secondterm" and both work

But I am not able to get the Boolean OR working, despite I have tried

```
q= "firstterm|secondterm"
q= "firstterm | secondterm"
q= "firstterm%7Csecondterm"
```

Any hints?

The documentation (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) has this explanation:

Your request can also use the Boolean NOT (-) and OR (|) operators to exclude videos or to find videos that are associated with one of several search terms. For example, to search for videos matching either "boating" or "sailing", set the q parameter value to boating|sailing. Similarly, to search for videos matching either "boating" or "sailing" but not "fishing", set the q parameter value to boating|sailing -fishing. Note that the pipe character must be URL-escaped when it is sent in your API request. The URL-escaped value for the pipe character is %7C.

Comment: What's the logic behind the OR operation ? Generally search term must be only one that you'll enter into the search box then why there is OR ?

Comment: Search is expensive in terms of quote (100). I need to run multiple searchs, so I am looking for ways I could find a set of videos instead of seaching one by one

Comment: @Susa maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55070494/12511801) will help you. Whatever the case, please keep updated your question. Also, if the problem persists, try report this issue in [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues).

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes thank you. The answer you linked is for AND which is not documented and does not seem to work either. OR is included in the documentation but yet I cannot get it to work.

Comment: @Susa did you search on [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues) for related problems? - some changes made on the API are not updated in the documentation.

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes I checked and could not find a related one. I have created the question there too. Thank you